# JWS Tokens generation in Elixir

Tags: encryption, jwt, elixir

I am trying to create JWS Tokens using Elixir.
What I've got:

- RSA Private key
- Base 64 encoded sha256 cert thumbprint
- Token header
- Token body

What I need:

- Token signature

JWS header looks like this

```
{ 
  "x5t#S256": {{ cert thumbprint }},
  "alg":"RS256"
}
```

To get the header token I just convert it to base64 and it's finished. Same with token body, I just convert the payload to base64.

The problem is getting token signature. As I understand it should be done like this:

```
token signature = base64(rsa-sha256(token header + "." + token body))
```

Q1: Is my logic here correct?

Q2: How to do the rsa-sha256 encryption on Elixir? Or is it the same thing as `:crypto.hash(sha256, ...)`?

Comment: Why would you reinvent a wheel? We have [`JOSE`](https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose) for that. Even if you don’t want to rely on 3rd party, check the code, it is OSS, there are all the algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not worked with JWS in Elixir, but I decided to try it as an exercise. You can generate the JWS signature using RSA like this:

```elixir
rsa_private_key = JOSE.JWK.from_pem_file("rsa-2048.pem")
header = %{"alg" => "RS256"}
payload = %{"example" => "foo"}

JOSE.JWT.sign(rsa_private_key, header, payload)
```

Output:

```elixir
{%{alg: :jose_jws_alg_rsa_pkcs1_v1_5},
 %{
   "payload" => "eyJleGFtcGxlIjoiZm9vIn0",
   "protected" => "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
   "signature" => "T2llXS2pGN-jev10Xd5EZQmaEih_dn9DIn5FJJg8ocEwIpNLupEWiNLz-5mP21z9JGpyYPFaRuq77AtKL67nP7KMDTpKKYJonOxQdL31sHU4vTKBRf-2XcVbDLGkST5dUMUWHOS106Sw_0x7DSiuFBUzkkYQ_lZKES8idVUp88Kx4uWU65Yoti0_Pu7aVLRGWDu0EiMjzuTPTBkMoib21VEVBqrJ4jiKXFudEFiNNSaV_GOH9yNZqyxwl4RhCYYT9U-Mda8Dc7xPjQk0LaJhwlaV91OhxJQHP2fGR8XkznHFlRRHTEsesYgl9OKZuSzVXoffydLc1VotphKUnG1WZQ"
 }}
```

And if you want it in short form:

```elixir
JOSE.JWT.sign(rsa_private_key, header, payload) |> JOSE.JWS.compact
```

Produces:

```elixir
{%{alg: :jose_jws_alg_rsa_pkcs1_v1_5},
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleGFtcGxlIjoiZm9vIn0.T2llXS2pGN-jev10Xd5EZQmaEih_dn9DIn5FJJg8ocEwIpNLupEWiNLz-5mP21z9JGpyYPFaRuq77AtKL67nP7KMDTpKKYJonOxQdL31sHU4vTKBRf-2XcVbDLGkST5dUMUWHOS106Sw_0x7DSiuFBUzkkYQ_lZKES8idVUp88Kx4uWU65Yoti0_Pu7aVLRGWDu0EiMjzuTPTBkMoib21VEVBqrJ4jiKXFudEFiNNSaV_GOH9yNZqyxwl4RhCYYT9U-Mda8Dc7xPjQk0LaJhwlaV91OhxJQHP2fGR8XkznHFlRRHTEsesYgl9OKZuSzVXoffydLc1VotphKUnG1WZQ"}
```

Here is the public key if you want to verify it:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAtRPXSP1W+5sgVLeRFYrrF6L7+gaEkPOWV2FDtPL/vRQH77bicJYb
oVytE/8JyHj8kH24hxwCy2LFl5fZLaIrqYBy1B1t8LtxTRVhi3JIc76IGZ3dfxrz
Dnv94Vu9BRxE7y37f7w8ulDVlGpmJhfCIMj8SYJrFWgHlQB2u7c/B43RE6uphRfD
nr4FkJ3ChUFKhuVZHm27r5/CllHNhMejA/WawtlWKdU33In1Xp2O+GxjLKoYuGGQ
U9MdrismDtn6bVcq5K97bByxelJel2rUG4sbtQk01gVtfun63rSzOP9EkNJOoRll
YDm3HQlDUY7+D9AMG3XlQuR7tlDXQtGIJQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The JWS header that I have is `%{
      "x5t#S256" => "C7DFYPKmoE6Ul8ZbpVohJXBPOUoXsgSki5kkaQKP1nc",
      "alg" => "RS256"
    }` and the end result for that needs to be `eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IkM3REZZUEttb0U2VWw4WmJwVm9oSlhCUE9Vb1hzZ1NraTVra2FRS1AxbmMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9` but it doesn't work using your method.

Comment: Sure it does, just replace the `header` with what you need. Here is the JWT (signed with my key) with that header, using the same code: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamu/7be1c5c1a3daed7842d193f7bfba3502/raw/540607360bd7dacc4eac4713f17358eca4029ccb/jwt

Comment: I noticed that this library [adds](https://hexdocs.pm/jose/JOSE.JWT.html#sign/3) `%{ "typ" => "JWT" }` to the header - maybe that's causing you problems?

Answer (score 0):

see this example on [JWT Auth with an Elixir on Phoenix](https://medium.com/@njwest/jwt-auth-with-an-elixir-on-phoenix-1-3-guardian-api-and-react-native-mobile-app-1bd00559ea51)

using `:bcrypt_elixir`, and `:guardian`